# Invalid Opcode, can't figure what is out of bounds or wrong

Tags: solidity

Sorry I know this is a common error but I've been reading through answers and struggling to see how I can apply them to my code. My code defines a Bond Struct, and a mapping of address to an array of bonds. The issue comes when creating a bond. I first pull all the bonds they own from that mapping into a temporary array, then I attempt to add the new bond into that array. Then I try to redefine the mapping for that address with the new bond. If this isn't the most efficient way or there are other ways to do it let me know!

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;
contract Bond {
    struct Bond {
        uint deposit_value;
        uint creationblock;
        uint redemptionblock;
    }
    mapping(address => Bond[]) BondLedger;

    function createBond() payable public {
        // For something temporary, this really shouldn't be storage
        // TODO fix this - its uses to much gas but can't get it to work because of feature
        // not yet here, so not really sure here
        Bond[] storage temporaryBondList;
        temporaryBondList = BondLedger[msg.sender];
        // Define new bond to insert into the creation list
        Bond memory newBond;
        newBond.deposit_value = msg.value;
        newBond.creationblock = block.number;
        newBond.redemptionblock = block.number + 100;
        //index starts at 0, so the .length will return something not already defined, but removing bonds has to be done properly
        // to avoid some nasty bugs
        temporaryBondList[temporaryBondList.length - 1] = newBond;
        BondLedger[msg.sender] = temporaryBondList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the first time `createBond` is called `BondLedger[msg.sender]` will be empty, so `temporaryBondList` will also be empty, then `temporaryBondList.length - 1` will overflow.

You can append a new element with

```
Bond storage newBond = BondLedger[msg.sender].push();

newBond.deposit_value = msg.value;
newBond.creationblock = block.number;
newBond.redemptionblock = block.number + 100;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you saved me a lot of time with this, especially evading that whole this feature does not exist bug that I implemented a shoddy workaround too. I still don't fully understand how it pushes a bond to the ledger then edits it, but it works fine so thank you!

Comment: @Frustrated The `.push()` appends an empty element to the end of the array and returns a reference so you can modify it. It is pretty handy so you don't have to create a temporary copy in memory.